# How to get selected tab to persist when refreshing model in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've inherited some existing Angular.js code, which I don't know a whole lot about.  A feature I've added is the ability to *refresh* the data in the view automatically every five seconds.  I've done this by changing my `init` function to call itself using the `$interval` function:

```
model.init = function (token) {
    model.token = token;
    model.dataUrl = GlobScope.rootPath + "upload/checkdata/" + token;

    var loadData = function() {
        commonHelper.apiGet("api/bases/" + model.token, function(result) {
            model.bases = result.data.bases;
            model.files = result.data.files;
            model.messages = result.data.messages;
        });
    }

    // Reload data every 5 seconds
    $interval(function () {
        loadData();
    }.bind(this), 5000);

    loadData();
}
```

This works great, and now as data on the server changes, it'll be updated on the client within five seconds.  However, there's one small problem.  My view has a bunch of tabs:

```
<tabset>
   <tab heading="Input">
      <br />
      Some hard coded tab
   </tab>
   <tab ng-repeat="baseData in dataProcessingModel.bases" heading="{{baseData.base}}">
      Other tabs here depending on the data in the model
   </tab>
</tabset>
```

Unfortunately, when the data is refreshed (every five seconds), the first tab is selected again.

What's the easiest way to get the currently selected tab to remain selected, while the data continues to refresh?

One thing I've tried is to bind the active tab to some part of the model, then I can perhaps set that again when the model changes:

```
<tab ng-repeat="baseData in dataProcessingModel.bases" heading="{{baseData.base}}" active="dataProcessingModel.activeTab == baseData.base">
```

Then in the `loadData` function:

var defaultTab = 'Input';

```
var loadData = function() {
    commonHelper.apiGet("api/bases/" + model.token, function(result) {
        model.activeTab = defaultTab;
        model.bases = result.data.bases;
        model.files = result.data.files;
        model.messages = result.data.messages;
    });
}
```

Next, I'd somehow have to change `defaultTab` every time a new tab is selected.  However, with this code, tabs become completely broken.  Clicking on a tab does nothing.

Is there a simple approach to this?  I dug through the [tab docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) and couldn't find anything of intested.

Comment: You are changing the active every time in loadData. You should consider to move the defailt selection to the init

Comment: What are you reloading? Is `model.bases` different each time? And what is the relationship of `model.bases` to `dataProcessingModel.bases`?

Comment: They're the same thing: `var model = $scope.dataProcessingModel;`

Comment: I'd say 99% of the time, I'm reloading the exact same data.  However, anything in model could be different so the UI needs to update the change..  I could have a mechanism that *detects* changes and only updates the changed properties, but that seemed like too much work..

Comment: I think tracking the active tab in the model is a dead end though.  Since clicking on a tab doesn't update the model, I now can't change tabs anymore..

Comment: @MikeChristensen, I'm fairly certain it has to do with the way `ng-repeat` tracks items - I'll write an answer shortly

Comment: @NewDev - Thanks!  The issue I'm running into is when you bind the `active` property of a `<tab>` to something in your model, you can't click on any tabs anymore.  Also, the `select` event no longer fires so I can't write an event handler that updates the model.  If I knew of a way to just set the tab in script, I could just remember the last tab and set it back when I reload the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with how `ng-repeat` tracks items. In your case, each "repeatable" item - `baseData` - is an object, and it is a different object every time you reload the items, so, `ng-repeat` has no way of knowing which is which. So, when you reload, completely new `tab` directives are created by `ng-repeat` and so `active` tab is lost.

This is when `track by` is used to tell `ng-repeat` how to track objects. It seems that in your case tracking by `$index` is most suitable (if you have some other immutable property to track the object by, you could use that as well, ex. `baseData.id`)

```
<tabset>
  <tab ng-repeat="baseData in dataProcessingModel.bases track by $index"
       heading="{{baseData.base}}">
    {{baseData.content}}
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/mazx5P65r3Ak9IlWvv95?p=preview)**

Comment: Nice!!  That works perfect.  I was actually working on some code that loops through the differences between the old `model.bases` and new `result.data.bases` and only copies over the updated properties, thus not destroying the array.  This works as well, but I like your way a lot better.

Comment: @MikeChristensen, that's what `ngRepeat` is doing under the covers for you, and `track by` tells it how to compare old vs new.

Comment: Yup, your way works a lot better when tabs are added or removed (My way just reset to the first tab in that case).  I wish I could give this answer way more upvotes!  I've  been working on this for hours..

Comment: @MikeChristensen, you could always award a bounty :p... kidding

Answer (score 0):

```
var defaultTab = 'Input'; // set this tab to currentTab before you call loadData()

  $interval(function () {
        loadData(defaultTab);
    }.bind(this), 5000);

    loadData(defaultTab);

var loadData = function(defaultTab) {
    commonHelper.apiGet("api/bases/" + model.token, function(result) {
        model.activeTab = defaultTab;
        model.bases = result.data.bases;
        model.files = result.data.files;
        model.messages = result.data.messages;
    });
```

}

Comment: I'm guessing because the active tab is now always bound to `model.activeTab`, as there's no code anywhere that actually changes that.

Comment: Sorry I don't follow.

Comment: you need to hold the active tab and store in model.activeTab.

Comment: Can you check by removing this line in loadData()  model.activeTab = defaultTab; after refresh it should hold active class for the current tab.

Comment: If I do that, nothing loads as it's now trying to bind to a property that doesn't exist..

Answer (score 0):

If you modify the `loadData()` function to accept an optional parameter, you can trigger the component to scroll where you want it to sometimes, and scroll to default if you pass in no parameters.

```
var defaultTab = 0;
var loadData = function(activeTab = defaultTab) {
    commonHelper.apiGet("api/bases/" + model.token, function(result) {
        model.activeTab = activeTab;
        // scrollTo(activeTab)
        model.bases = result.data.bases;
        model.files = result.data.files;
        model.messages = result.data.messages;
    });
};
```

Comment: It seems that you can't bind the active tab to the model since you then can't change the tab without changing the model, and there's no even that gets fired when you click on a tab.  So, I think I need some other approach.